# How can I improve my translation?

Tags: translation, mandarin

拥有豪华的住宅和一批在菲律宾。 开放的外国护照持有人。 拥有您梦寐以求的房子在该国的，而不仅仅是一座公寓式的！

ENGLISH

> Own luxurious house and lot in the Philippines. Open for Foreign passport holders. Own you dream house in the country and not just  a condominium(apartment)!

Is there any discrepancy with my mandarin translation? If so please help in correct my errors. 谢谢!

Comment: This looks like translation done by a machine totally. You can even use Google Translate to get better result than that. So this question doesn't show any personal effort. And simply asking for translation is a discouraged behaviour of this website. Downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Original translation is very unclear.  The original Enligsh style should not be directly translated into Chinese.
"Own" might be translated to 购入/购置.  And "a lot" should be translated to 其他豪华物资/资产 I guess?

I guess this is an advertisement?

It should be (sentences reordered and more advertisement-like) "住惯了公寓，想拥有属于自己的梦幻别墅？只需要您拥有护照，即可在菲律宾购入豪华别墅以及更多菲律宾资产".

Answer (score 0):

> *Own luxurious house and lot in the Philippines.*
>
> *拥有豪华的住宅和一批在菲律宾。*

- "lot" here means "地段" (a piece of land). Think 'parking lot'
- In English, the location is usually placed after the verb, as in this sentence, but in Chinese, location is usually placed before the verb

The first sentence should be translated as follow:

"**在菲律宾拥有豪华的住宅和地段**"

or

"**在菲律宾拥有豪宅和地段**" (shorten 豪华的住宅 to 豪宅 which is a common term)

~

> *Open for Foreign passport holders.*
>
> *开放的外国护照持有人。*

- "Open for" here means "开放给" in Chinese, but the sentence didn't state open for foreign passport holders to do what, and from the context, we can presume it is 认购' (to acquire)
- the more appropriate term than "Open for" is 'welcome' (欢迎 )

The second sentence should be translated as follow:

"**欢迎外国护照持有人认购。**"

~

> *Own you dream house in the country and not just a condominium(apartment)!*
>
> *拥有您梦寐以求的房子在该国的，而不仅仅是一座公寓式的！*

- "dream house" 理想的房子
- It should be "own your dream house", not "own you dream house"
- "condominium" is a noun for "公寓" , not "condominium style" (公寓式的)

The third sentence should be translated as follow:

"**在该国拥有一座您理想的房子，而不仅仅是一座公寓**" (again, location before verb)

~

It is obviously an advertisement. The whole thing should be written as a paragraph:

> "(如果你想)在菲律宾拥有豪宅和地段," - "(if you want to) own luxurious house and lot in the Philippines,"
>
> (我们这里)欢迎外国护照持有人认购。 - "we welcome foreign passport holders to acquire them here."
>
> (您可以)在该国拥有一座您理想的房子，而不仅仅是一座公寓! - "(you can) own your dream house in the country and not just a condominium (apartment)!"

or written as a bulletin list:

> - 在菲律宾拥有豪宅和地段 -  own luxurious house and lot in the Philippines
> - 欢迎外国护照持有人认购 - "welcome foreign passport holders to acquire
> - 在该国拥有一座您理想的房子，而不仅仅是一座公寓 - own your dream house in the country and not just a condominium (apartment)

Comment: 地段 doesn't mean *a piece of land*. It means *position or location*, so 好地段，地段差 mean *good or bad locations*. Lot can simply be 一块地.